# Beautifulsoup only returning first item

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

although I am seemingly not the first person who has had this problem, I was not able to find the answer to my problem.

I am scraping an HTML table and although I am trying to loop through it, I am only getting the first row from the table.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



# Webpage connection
html = "https://www.wegochem.com/chemicals/organic-intermediates/supplier-distributor"
r=requests.get(html)
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
# Grab title-artist classes and store in recordList

wegoList = soup.find_all("tbody")

try:
    for items in wegoList:
        material = items.find("td", {"class": "click_whole_cell",}).get_text().strip()

        cas = items.find("td", {"class": "text-center",}).get_text().strip()

        category = items.find("div", {"class": "text-content short-text",}).get_text().strip()

    print(material,cas,category)
except:
    pass
```

the result for the first row is coming out correctly: (1,2-Dimethylimidazole 1739-84-0 Organic Intermediates, Plastic, Resin & Rubber, Coatings);
however the for loop is not looping through the table.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for items in wegoList:` loops through list of `tbody` then you try to extract attributes from entire table but you should loop through every `tr` row:

```
wegoList = soup.find_all("tbody")

try:
    soup=BeautifulSoup(wegoList.__str__(),"html.parser")
    trs = soup.find_all('tr') #Makes list of rows

    for tr in trs: 
        material = tr.find("td", {"class": "click_whole_cell",}).get_text().strip()

        cas = tr.find("td", {"class": "text-center",}).get_text().strip()

        category = tr.find("div", {"class": "text-content short-text",}).get_text().strip()

    print(material,cas,category)
```

Comment: this also works, maybe even better! thank you to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



# Webpage connection
html = "https://www.wegochem.com/chemicals/organic-intermediates/supplier-distributor"
r=requests.get(html)
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
# Grab title-artist classes and store in recordList

wegoList = soup.find_all("tbody")

try:
    for items in wegoList:
        material = items.find_all("td", {"class": "click_whole_cell",})
        for i in material:
            print(i.get_text().strip())

        cas = items.find_all("td", {"class": "text-center",})
        for i in cas:
            print(i.get_text().strip())

        category = items.find_all("div", {"class": "text-content short-text",})
        for i in category:
            print(i.get_text().strip())

except:
    pass
```

> Updated code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



# Webpage connection
html = "https://www.wegochem.com/chemicals/organic-intermediates/supplier-distributor"
r=requests.get(html)
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
# Grab title-artist classes and store in recordList

wegoList = soup.find_all("tbody")


for items in wegoList:
    material = items.find_all("td", {"class": "click_whole_cell",})
    cas = items.find_all("td", {"class": "text-center",})
    category = items.find_all("div", {"class": "text-content short-text",})
    for i in zip(material,cas,category):
        print(i[0].get_text().strip(),i[1].get_text().strip(),i[2].get_text().strip())
```

output:

```
1,2-Dimethylimidazole 1739-84-0 Organic Intermediates, Plastic, Resin & Rubber, Coatings
1,6-Hexanediol 629-11-8 Adhesives & Sealants, Industrial Chemicals, Inks & Digital Inks, Organic Intermediates, Plastic, Resin & Rubber, Coatings
2,2,4-Trimethyl-1,3-Pentanediol Monoisobutyrate 25265-77-4 Inks & Digital Inks, Oil Field Services, Organic Intermediates, Solvents & Degreasers, Coatings
2,6-Dichloroaniline 608-31-1 Agricultural Chemicals, Crop Protection, Organic Intermediates
```

Comment: thank you, this extracts all data but separated into all all material items, all can and all category - not in a list each x each.